# How does Task Manager differentiate "Windows Processes" in Win10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, task-manager

I have a number of shell extensions for various development projects, and they tend to cause a lot of issues with Windows Explorer. By far the most common is that the Start Menu won't pop up when clicked/pressed or won't do anything when I type.

I can solve this by going into Task Manager and restarting specifically the Explorer process listed under "Windows Processes" without having to restart any of the open file explorer processes, which is hugely convenient when I'm working in a lot of folders.

What I want to do is identify that particular process and taskkill it, so I need to know how Task Manager identifies something as a "Windows Process" as opposed to a bog-standard "App". Googling hasn't turned up anything. Anyone know?

Comment: Explorer is a particular process, nothing hiding behind it, it is a system process.

Comment: Also, in recent versions of windows 10, when you choose "restart process" windows will attempt to close explorer.exe, reopen it, then launch all previous explorer windows. I'd say, that is a feature of the Task Manager.

Comment: I understand this, but there are multiple explorer.exe processes listed under Apps (the regular browse windows) and one single explorer.exe process listed under Windows Processes (the shell). That one single process is what I want to target.